# Python concatenating to np array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm parsing a bunch of formatted reports into a numpy array using genfromtxt. I'm doing that in a loop using np.concatenate. The challenge is that concatenate does not like the first iteration when the array is not yet defined.

As a workaround for now I tried reading one representative report ahead of the loop, but that gives the data entries from that report twice. The problem is to teach np.concatenate how the array looks like.

```
data= np.genfromtxt('data_0.500.rpt',dtype=None)
data_1= data

for v in frange(0.460, 0.651, 0.010):
    fn= 'data_' + '{:4.3f}'.format(v) +'.rpt'
    if os.path.exists(fn):
        print 'Reading : ' + fn
        data= np.concatenate((data,np.genfromtxt(fn,dtype=None)))
```

I guess I would need a way to create a 0-length `data` array upfront from the format encountered in the `data_0.500.rpt` file.

How would I do that?

Your feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Accumulate them all into a list, then call `np.concatenate` on the list of arrays, which should be more efficient than this horribly inefficient approach of concatenating incrementally in a loop.

Comment: Just spelling out what @juanpa.arrivillaga is suggesting: `fns = filter(os.path.exists, map('data_{:4.3f}.rpt'.format, frange(0.460, 0.5651, 0.010)))`, `data = np.concatenate([np.genfromtxt(fn, dtype=None) for fn in fns])`